# How come assigning this obvious wrong type does not give a compiler error?

Tags: c++, templates, types, compilation

I'm currently in the process of trying to write a tree data structure. I was lead down this path after trying to create an iterator for my original data structure, and then learning about the STL specs.

I'll try to condense my code a bit and still show what confuses me about the code not compiling. If something is missing I'll gladly add it later.

```
// Relevant bits of tree.hpp
template <class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
class tree
{
public:
    struct NODE
    {
        T                  data;
        std::vector<NODE*> children;
        NODE*              parent;
        NODE*              right;

        // Not shown here: size()
    };

    typedef Alloc                           allocator_type;
    typedef typename Alloc::value_type      value_type;
    typedef value_type&                     reference;
    typedef const value_type&               const_reference;
    typedef typename Alloc::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename Alloc::size_type       size_type;

    class iterator
    {
    public:
        typedef typename Alloc::difference_type difference_type;
        typedef typename Alloc::value_type      value_type;
        typedef typename Alloc::reference       reference;
        typedef typename Alloc::pointer         pointer;
        typedef std::forward_iterator_tag       iterator_category;

        iterator(NODE* node) : currentNode_(node) {}
        iterator(const iterator& i) : currentNode_(i.currentNode_) {}

        iterator& operator++ ();

        // Not shown here: operator==, operator!=, operator*, operator->

    private:
        NODE* currentNode_;
    };

    // Not shown here: constructors, begin(), end(), size(), empty(), etc...

private:
    NODE root_;
};
```

---

```
// Relevant bits of tree.cpp
template <class T, class Alloc>
typename tree<T, Alloc>::iterator&
tree<T, Alloc>::iterator::operator++ ()
{
    if (!currentNode_->children.empty())
        currentNode_ = currentNode_->children.front();

    else if (currentNode_->right != nullptr)
        currentNode_ = currentNode_->right;

    else {
        while (currentNode_->parent->right == nullptr)
            currentNode_ = currentNode_->parent;
        currentNode_ = currentNode_->parent->right;
    }
    currentNode_ = "abc - Just some random string, definitely not a NODE*";
    return *this;
}
```

How come I can assign seemingly any random thing to `currentNode_`? Furthermore, even if I return something that is obviously not a `iterator&`, or even just leave out the return statement all together, the code still happily compiles. What is going on?

I haven't tested what happens when I actually call the code yet, since I haven't implemented actual code to populate the tree yet. I wanted to make sure I get these basics right before I continue with that.

**Ninja edit**: To compile, I call `find src/ -name "*.cpp" | xargs g++ -Isrc/ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu++0x || exit 1`.

Comment: The thing with templates is that it is not an error unless you instantiate it. So as long as you don't try to use `tree<T, Alloc>::iterator::operator++` the code will compile. Try using it and see what happens. OR even try declaring a tree (*I think the error should show*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `currentNode_` is dependent on the type of the template, that part of compilation is not done until you actually instantiate/use the function. Once you call your operator, you'll get the expected compilation error on the literal string assignment.